# How to Parse JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON response. But I couldn't be able to parse data through php.
e.g. if I want to get @id.how. Can I  do it? I have tried with this line of code but couldn't get anything

```
$json = json_decode($jsonData,true);
echo $json['expose.expose'][0]['@id'];
```

```html
{
  "expose.expose": {
    "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798",
    "@id": "88951798",
    "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
    "@creation": "2016-06-16T14:27:23.000+02:00",
    "@publishDate": "2016-06-16T14:27:23.000+02:00",
    "@contactFormType": "LONG",
    "realEstate": {
      "@xsi.type": "expose:ApartmentRent",
      "@id": "88951798",
      "externalId": "54",
      "title": "** Azubi's \/ Berufspendler - helles WG Zimmer in ruhiger Zweck- WG - Neustadt - nä. Flughafen **",
      "creationDate": "2016-06-16T14:27:23.000+02:00",
      "lastModificationDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
      "address": {
        "postcode": "28199",
        "city": "Bremen \/ Neustadt",
        "quarter": "Neuenland",
        "geoHierarchy": {
          "continent": {
            "geoCodeId": 1,
            "fullGeoCodeId": "1"
          },
          "country": {
            "name": "Deutschland",
            "geoCodeId": 276,
            "fullGeoCodeId": "1276"
          },
          "region": {
            "name": "Bremen",
            "geoCodeId": 5,
            "fullGeoCodeId": "1276005"
          },
          "city": {
            "name": "Bremen",
            "geoCodeId": 1,
            "fullGeoCodeId": "1276005001"
          },
          "quarter": {
            "name": "Neuenland",
            "geoCodeId": 147,
            "fullGeoCodeId": "1276005001147"
          },
          "neighbourhood": {
            "geoCodeId": 4011000021701
          }
        }
      },
      "descriptionNote": "** WG Zimmer in ruhiger Zweck-WG - mit Gemeinschaftsgarten **\n\nEs erwartet Sie ein kleines, helles Zimmer mit Echtholzfußboden in einer ruhigen 3er Wohngemeinschaft in der Bremer Neustadt.\n\nBitte geben Sie IMMER Ihre Telefonnummer mit an!",
      "furnishingNote": "Das Zimmer ist ca. 13 qm groß, weiß gestrichen und hat einen gepflegten Dielenfußboden. In Gemeinschaft wird ein Vollbad mit Badewanne, Dusche und separaten WC genutzt. Ebenfalls eine helle freundliche Küche mit Einbauküche - zusammen mit dem Zimmer ca. 25 qm - . Ein kleiner Garten befindet sich am Haus, den alle Mieter nutzen dürfen. \n\nIn der WG wohnen zwei weitere ruhige Mieter, gesucht wird eine ergänzende ruige Person. Ideal ist diese WG für Berufspendler, Berufsstarter, Auszubildende oder Studenten.",
      "locationNote": "Das Wohnhaus befindet sich links der Weser im Bremer Stadteil Neustadt. Kurze Wege zum Flughafen (mit dem Fahrrad 6 Minuten) und gute Anbindung zur B75 und A281. Einkaufsmöglchkeiten befinden sich in der Nähe der Wohnung. Mit Bus & Bahn erreicht man die City in wenigen Minuten.",
      "otherNote": "Für weitere Informationen und Besichtigungen stehen wir Ihnen gern zur Verfügung. Bitte geben Sie immer Ihre Telefonnummer mit an!! Gesetzlicher Hinweis: Bitte beachten Sie, dass Sie uns mit Anforderung weiterer Informationen und Unterlagen zu diesem Immobilienangebot Ihre Einwilligung im Sinne des § 7 UWG geben, Sie über weitere Angebotsdetails telefonisch, per Email oder Fax zu unterrichten sowie Ihnen ggf. ein anderes geeignetes Mietangebot vorzustellen. Wir wollen unter keinen Umständen, dass unsere Kontaktaufnahme für Sie eine \"unzumutbare Belästigung\" im Sinne des § 7 UWG darstellt. Aus diesem Grund weisen wir ausdrücklich darauf hin, dass Sie jederzeit Ihre Einwilligung formlos telefonisch oder schriftlich bei uns widerrufen können.",
      "attachments": [
        {
          "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment",
          "attachment": [
            {
              "@xsi.type": "common:Picture",
              "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment\/1",
              "@id": "1",
              "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "title": "Schlafzimmer Fensterseite",
              "floorplan": "false",
              "titlePicture": "true",
              "urls": [
                {
                  "url": [
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_118x118",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/118x118%3E\/extent\/118x118\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_210x210",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/210x210%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_540x540",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/540x540%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_AND_CROP",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/legacy_thumbnail\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "WHITE_FILLING",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/extent\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@xsi.type": "common:Picture",
              "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment\/2",
              "@id": "2",
              "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "title": "Schlafzimmer Rückseite",
              "floorplan": "false",
              "titlePicture": "false",
              "urls": [
                {
                  "url": [
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/527\/495413527-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_118x118",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/527\/495413527-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/118x118%3E\/extent\/118x118\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_210x210",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/527\/495413527-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/210x210%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_540x540",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/527\/495413527-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/540x540%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/527\/495413527-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_AND_CROP",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/527\/495413527-0.jpg\/ORIG\/legacy_thumbnail\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "WHITE_FILLING",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/527\/495413527-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/extent\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@xsi.type": "common:Picture",
              "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment\/3",
              "@id": "3",
              "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "title": "Küche E58",
              "floorplan": "false",
              "titlePicture": "false",
              "urls": [
                {
                  "url": [
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/531\/495413531-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_118x118",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/531\/495413531-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/118x118%3E\/extent\/118x118\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_210x210",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/531\/495413531-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/210x210%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_540x540",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/531\/495413531-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/540x540%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/531\/495413531-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_AND_CROP",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/531\/495413531-0.jpg\/ORIG\/legacy_thumbnail\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "WHITE_FILLING",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig04\/N\/495\/413\/531\/495413531-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/extent\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@xsi.type": "common:Picture",
              "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment\/4",
              "@id": "4",
              "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "title": "Badezimmer",
              "floorplan": "false",
              "titlePicture": "false",
              "urls": [
                {
                  "url": [
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/533\/495413533-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_118x118",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/533\/495413533-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/118x118%3E\/extent\/118x118\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_210x210",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/533\/495413533-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/210x210%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_540x540",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/533\/495413533-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/540x540%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/533\/495413533-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_AND_CROP",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/533\/495413533-0.jpg\/ORIG\/legacy_thumbnail\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "WHITE_FILLING",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/533\/495413533-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/extent\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@xsi.type": "common:Picture",
              "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment\/5",
              "@id": "5",
              "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "title": "Dusche",
              "floorplan": "false",
              "titlePicture": "false",
              "urls": [
                {
                  "url": [
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/537\/495413537-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_118x118",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/537\/495413537-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/118x118%3E\/extent\/118x118\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_210x210",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/537\/495413537-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/210x210%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_540x540",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/537\/495413537-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/540x540%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/537\/495413537-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_AND_CROP",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/537\/495413537-0.jpg\/ORIG\/legacy_thumbnail\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "WHITE_FILLING",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/537\/495413537-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/extent\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@xsi.type": "common:Picture",
              "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment\/6",
              "@id": "6",
              "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "title": "separates WC",
              "floorplan": "false",
              "titlePicture": "false",
              "urls": [
                {
                  "url": [
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig01\/N\/495\/413\/540\/495413540-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_118x118",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig01\/N\/495\/413\/540\/495413540-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/118x118%3E\/extent\/118x118\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_210x210",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig01\/N\/495\/413\/540\/495413540-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/210x210%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_540x540",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig01\/N\/495\/413\/540\/495413540-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/540x540%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig01\/N\/495\/413\/540\/495413540-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_AND_CROP",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig01\/N\/495\/413\/540\/495413540-0.jpg\/ORIG\/legacy_thumbnail\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "WHITE_FILLING",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig01\/N\/495\/413\/540\/495413540-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/extent\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "@xsi.type": "common:Picture",
              "@xlink.href": "https:\/\/rest.immobilienscout24.de\/restapi\/api\/search\/v1.0\/expose\/88951798\/attachment\/7",
              "@id": "7",
              "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
              "title": "Garten",
              "floorplan": "false",
              "titlePicture": "false",
              "urls": [
                {
                  "url": [
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/545\/495413545-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_118x118",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/545\/495413545-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/118x118%3E\/extent\/118x118\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_210x210",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/545\/495413545-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/210x210%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_540x540",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/545\/495413545-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/540x540%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/545\/495413545-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "SCALE_AND_CROP",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/545\/495413545-0.jpg\/ORIG\/legacy_thumbnail\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    },
                    {
                      "@scale": "WHITE_FILLING",
                      "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/545\/495413545-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%%3E\/extent\/%WIDTH%x%HEIGHT%\/format\/jpg"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "referencePriceServiceCall": "https:\/\/www.immobilienscout24.de\/realestatevaluation\/ajax\/v2.2\/referenceprice\/region\/5\/city\/1\/district\/147?realEstateType=0&price=8.40&livingArea=25&firstTimeUse=false",
      "referencePriceApiCall": "https:\/\/www.immobilienscout24.de\/realestatevaluation\/ajax\/v2.2\/referenceprice\/region\/5\/city\/1\/district\/147?realEstateType=0&price=8.40&livingArea=25&firstTimeUse=false",
      "state": "ACTIVE",
      "titlePicture": {
        "@id": "1",
        "@modification": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
        "@creation": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
        "@publishDate": "2016-06-24T12:40:46.896Z",
        "title": "Schlafzimmer Fensterseite",
        "floorplan": "false",
        "titlePicture": "true",
        "urls": [
          {
            "url": [
              {
                "@scale": "SCALE_60x60",
                "@href": "https:\/\/pictureis24-a.akamaihd.net\/pic\/orig02\/N\/495\/413\/525\/495413525-0.jpg\/ORIG\/resize\/60x60%3E\/extent\/60x60\/format\/jpg"
              
      
    },
    
  }
}
```

Comment: `$json['expose.expose']['@id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `expose.expose` is an associative array, but you are accessing it like an array of arrays. You can access its members directly like this:

```
echo $json['expose.expose']['@id'];
```